# RSA Decryption on PHP

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I'm trying to use RSA on PHP, and so far I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
So basically, I have an RSA-encrypted string that I got from a site, which I then check if it is the same with the `public_key`.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$rsa = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();

$secure_signature = urldecode(*<base64 encoded signature>*);
$decodedSig = base64_decode($secure_signature);

$public_key = *<base64 encoded key>*;

$rsa->loadKey($public_key);
$res = $rsa->decrypt($decodedSig);

echo $res;
```

I came across an error where it says `Decryption error`. I then looked at other RSA public keys and noticed that it has the `----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----` and `----END PUBLIC KEY----` texts on the front and at the end of the key, respectively.

So I changed the value of my `$public_key`.

```
$public_key = "---BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----\n*<base64 encoded key>*----END PUBLIC KEY----";
```

After that, it doesn't show any errors but it also doesn't show anything.
How can I know if I did this right? Am I missing something?

Comment: phpseclib uses the more secure OAEP padding by default. PKCS1 padding, however, is more common. To use PKCS1 padding you'd need to do `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to archive. Your code says "signature" and your going to decrypt? For decryption you need your **private key**, for verifikation of a signature you take the **public key**.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through this. If you happen to var_dump the decrypt method response then you will get bool(false) or maybe NULL. Notifying that encryption process i.e. the way it has encrypted is not matching up with decryption process. Thus this issue. Check your encryption & decryption steps / process. Look at the difference.